# How does one add kali tools such as backtrack on linux mint?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I am stuck at adding kali repositories and tools such as theHarvester and BackTrack on linux mint.

Comment: please post in detail what is the actual problem you are facing

Answer (score 0):

you can have it on virtual machine on linuxmint .

anyway you can find out backtrack tools name and install all of them from github and author's   on your own os .